# How can I get the data from the SimpleXMLElement in php array

Tags: php, xml-parsing

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 1.1 [encoding] => UTF-8 ) [forgotPassword] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [message] => User is not found. [status] => error ) )
```

Comment: i want to get the result from it in php

I am using this :
 $response->forgetPassword->message;
but never get the answer

Comment: You should provide more context, *inside* your question (edit it). Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I use this from the PHP manual comments:

```php
/**
 * function xml2array
 *
 * This function is part of the PHP manual.
 *
 * The PHP manual text and comments are covered by the Creative Commons 
 * Attribution 3.0 License, copyright (c) the PHP Documentation Group
 *
 * @author  k dot antczak at livedata dot pl
 * @date    2011-04-22 06:08 UTC
 * @link    http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php#103617
 * @license http://www.php.net/license/index.php#doc-lic
 * @license http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 * @license CC-BY-3.0 <http://spdx.org/licenses/CC-BY-3.0>
 */
function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{
    foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
        $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

    return $out;
}
```

You should try it.